# For any integer $n \ge 3 $, prove that $D_n$ has a subgroup of order 4 if and only if n is even

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $H \lt D_n$, $|H|=4$

Since $|D_n|=2n$, by Lagrange's Theorem 
$$4|2n$$
$$2n=4k $$ for some $\in \Bbb Z^+$

$$n=2k$$ 
thus $n$ is even

Conversely suppose $n$ is even.  then how to show $D_n$ has subgroup of order 4 ?

please give me a hint please!

Comment: When $n$ is even, you can construct a subgroup of order 4 pretty easily. As a hint, one of the elements of the subgroup is going to correspond to a reflection of the rigid body.

Comment: Hint. If $n$ is doubly even there's a subgroup of rotations that works. If $n$ singly even, think about the rotation through $\pi$ and the reflection over the $x$-axis.

Comment: Start with any two distinct reflections that will commute....!

Answer (score 3):

$n$ is even implies $R_{180} \in D_n$ and is of order $2$. So for any reflection $F$, we have $$R_{180}F=FR_{180}$$ and note that any reflection has order $2$ and the latter element has also order $2$.

Hence  .................. is your required subgroup!

Comment: ahh! you use $a,b \in G$ and each element of oreder is 2 and commute each other. then $\{e,a,b,ab\}$ always subgroup of order 4 in $G$ right?

Answer (score 2):

The dihedral groups $D_n$ are supersolvable, hence the converse of Lagrange's Theorem always holds. Since $4\mid D_{2n}$ for even $n\ge 2$, there exists a subgroup of order $4$.

References:

[Dihedral group is supersolvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189167/dihedral-group-is-supersolvable?rq=1)

[Complete classification of the groups for which converse of Lagrange's Theorem holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144077/complete-classification-of-the-groups-for-which-converse-of-lagranges-theorem-h/2144109#2144109)