# Prove that the dihedral groups $D_n$ are all Lagrangian

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

I was reading a book on group theory and there was problem in the book that states:

> Prove that the dihedral groups $D_n$ are all Lagrangian for $n\geq3$.

Apologies the previous hint was not for this question.

If anyone could answer this question is would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What definition of $D_n$ are you using? Which book are you referring to?

Comment: You are new, so you may not know: **do not remove content** like you just did; especially when there is already an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

All dihedral groups are supersolvable and hence Lagrangian, i.e., the converse of Lagrange's theorem holds.

References:

[Dihedral group is supersolvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189167/dihedral-group-is-supersolvable)

[Complete classification of the groups for which converse of Lagrange's Theorem holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144077/complete-classification-of-the-groups-for-which-converse-of-lagranges-theorem-h/2144109#2144109)